# Pass shell variable to the beginning of awk search pattern

Tags: bash, shell, variables, awk, quoting

I could pass a variable into the pattern of awk but I'm not sure what I should do if this variable is at the beginning of the pattern so here is an expample code

```
    awk -v pattern="$i" '
       $0 ~ /^$pattern/{print}
    ' input.txt
```

The code below works for searching the pattern only,

```
    awk -v pattern="$i" '
       $0 ~ pattern{print}
    ' input.txt
```

What should I do to combine variables and regular expressions?

Comment: Replace in last code `"$i"` with `"^$i"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following.

```
awk -v pattern="$i" 'match($0,"^" pattern)' Input_file
```

---

---

***2nd solution with `index`***:

```
awk -v pattern="$i" 'index($0,pattern)==1'  Input_file
```

---

---

***3rd solution using `substr`:***

i- To get a match.

```
awk -v pattern="$i" 'BEGIN{var_len=length(pattern)} substr($0,1,var_len)~pattern  Input_file
```

ii- To get EXACT match:

```
awk -v pattern="$i" 'BEGIN{var_len=length(pattern)} substr($0,1,var_len)==pattern'  Input_file
```

Answer (score 3):

```
awk -v pattern="$i" '
   $0 ~ ("^"pattern){print}
' input.txt
```

The parens probably aren't necessary but they help with clarity.